# How do i get middle tab selected on click on a linkbutton in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working in an application in which there is a linkbutton inbox, when user clicks on it "default.aspx" page opens with 1st tab selected but i required that in case of inbox clicked middle tab must be selected and shows opened.when user not clicks on inbox "default.aspx" 's page 1st tab must be selected.Click event code is

```
protected void btnInbox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
}
```

Comment: please tell us what TAB are you reffering to,is it ajax Tab,CSS Tabs etc ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this at the starting of body tag of your aspx page

```
$('#nameOftabs').tabs({ selected: index });
```

Where index would be the default tab that you would like selected.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be better to use jquery Ui tabs for your requirement rather than write server script for it.

Comment: I am using jquery Ui tabs but don 't know how to handle this case.